# Android: Shared Preferences architecture

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've just started developing an Android application and am thinking of using `SharedPreferences` to save persistent data like the username and password. One question I have is in regards to the registration of a user for the first time. When a user attempts to register on a new mobile, how does the back-end verify the uniqueness of the username? Is there some kind of one-time communication to Google's servers to verify uniqueness which then sends back a token if it's unique otherwise a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android lets you use Google sign-in, which removes the need to maintain your own user/password combinations. Check this page on Android Training site for more information: https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin